# How to deploy an application consisting of a front-end and back-end on one storage device

Tags: java, mysql, model-view-controller, deployment, backend

I need to submit some software to the university I attend and this software must be runnable from a storage device. The software was designed with an MVC architectural structure and was implemented using Java for the frontend and MySQL CE for the backend.

The bulk of my experience has been with front-end java development in Eclipse so I am quite uncertain about how to go about deployment when there is a database involved. This is actually the first 'real' application ive written which involves a database and my first attempt at implementing the the MVC pattern.

Im only a student at this point so please bear with me. This is what I know:

- I can compress my java files into a jar and deploy it no problem (this I have done before)
- To get this program to work I had to include a MySQL connector so this must be provided but it seems like this will all be part of the compressed jar (I obviously have some uncertainties surrounding deployment, sorry)
- I wrote two scripts, one to create my database and one to populate it with test data and these must be provided somehow.
- Whoever is running my software must obviously have a MySQL CE version running on their system so this must be somehow provided

I have searched around for a solution but I study by distance, so I don't really have any source of guidance aside from the awesome people on stackoverflow and the less helpful google search.

Possible solutions in my head:

- somehow write an installer/configuration file similar to what is provided with commercial software (this is not my optimal choice due to the fact that I have 2 more weeks till submission and I am prepping for exams but if it is the only way please point me in the right direction .. its something I will need to know soon anyway)
- On my searches through Stack Overflow I saw something which suggested that another version of MySQL - MySQL lite or something similar, could be used in these situations (again not optimal due to the amount of rework involved, but if its got to be...)

Thanks in advance

Comment: yes, if your application uses small amount of data, use SQLlite. it depends on the task you have done so far

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what exactly would that mean for deployment though? And would the scripts from MySQL CE be directly compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
How can I embed SQL to your application
```

Till the time I know you can not embed `MySQL` to your application. Rather it will be a *necessary component.*

1. So make a **user interface** that will guide the user to provide the `database name`. Then you will use this **database name to create a database** (and also tables which are used by your appliction).
2. If your **connection encounters error** then tell the user to install `MYSQL` (Also it will be on your documentation). Then save this **database name, username** and **password** as configurations for your application (may be XML file) but for security reasons do not forget to encrypt password.
3. Use saved credentials for your work.

I was having the same problem earlier in my college project and I fixed it in the same way.

**One strong** reason not to provide MYSQL or any other software as embedded with your application is the Copyright. So respect the others and let the user to take the headache.

**Edit:**
When you are showing splash screen, of course your will run the test connection, in this phase you will validate the database and tables and all resources to run your application, if some error(means some thing wrong with DB) the show error to user that please configure database and show configuration help (repeat step 1, 2, 3). When it is configured correctly go on.

As seemed you are confusing some thing that you are unable to tell?

Comment: for deployement concept see this (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_deployment). As per compatibility issue it reside on different platforms, but as you are using java so no issue, and for MYSQL, it is connector headache to do job (i.e connect or execute your commands)

Comment: I am also waiting if some one with batter solution, welcome.

Comment: Thanks, thats very helpful, especially the copyright bit. I don't know how that slipped me. Your answer has already cleared up one or two confusions I had. I had simply hardcoded the load drivers, local address, port number, db name, db username and password into an 'initializer' class but it was obvious that this wasn't the right way. So these are to be stored in an xml file.

Comment: Ahhh, so you will execute the create table commands from within your java application then? I had only used the java for querying. Is there anyway to run the external script on the user's pc?

Comment: sorry for delay, actually if u r using for querying only, then u mush ensure that the database user provided matching ur criteria (means it has same table, and columns etc.), no need to run external script. for what purpose u want to run external script?

Comment: To allow for exactly that. What i mean is that in the code I access the table 'students' in the data base 'prototype' so I want to know how to run the SQL script which will create the database 'prototype' and the table 'students' before the actual program runs.

Comment: Thanks man, u've been really helpful. I think ive got it down now